# Ubuntu 14.04.2 boots, then freezes after 1-2 mins. Mouse pointer still moves

Tags: 14.04, macbook, macosx

Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed on MacBook runnig OS X Mavericks.

The Ubuntu installation will boot and seems to behave fine but then after 1-2 minutes it freezes. Note that I can still move the mouse pointer around, but I can't click on anything and the keyboard is not responsive.

Can anyone suggest what may cause this, how to diagnose?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the problem is with the nouveau display drivers that Ubuntu uses by default. Once booted, I quickly activated the nVidia third party drivers before it froze. Restarted and have had a more consistent experience since.